# Why alert statements in JSP don't work during an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm doing an ajax call to a jsp to render the html content I'm sending as a pdf. In the jsp I have a few alert statements that are not being called. Is it because I'm making an ajax request?
I don't want to use the alert in the else block of the js.

```
var objHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
objHTTP.open("post", "myJspToRenderAsPdf.jsp", true);
objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/html");
objHTTP.responseType = 'blob';
objHTTP.onload = function(event) {
if (objHTTP.status == 200) {

/*
Code to download pdf
*/

} else {
alert('PDF was not generated');

}
};
objHTTP.send(strData);
```

jsp code:

```
<%
if(something.equals("true")){

%>
<script language = "javascript">
alert("alert not working");
</script>

<%
 }
%>
```

Comment: So the problem is that the alert in the JSP you're returning isn't popping up?

Comment: Yes... that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

The Script returned from the async call will not get evaluated by the javascript engine. Your best bet is to Evluate your return script explicetly. By calling javascript eval method.

Something like this

```
objHTTP.onload = function(event) {
if (objHTTP.status == 200) {
document.getElementById("SomeDIv").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
eval(document.getElementById('toExecute').innerHTML); // Relavent for You
/*
Code to download pdf   
*/

} else {
alert('PDF was not generated');

}
};
```

And in JSP

```
%>
<script id="toExecute" language = "javascript">
alert("alert not working");
</script>
<%
```

The above line `eval(...)` will evaluated your javascript and you can have your alert.